# Creating a new user in database

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am having an issue creating a new user with parse.com.. My code seems correct but for some reason whenever i enter a new user, it does not register.. Can someone help me with this issue?

```
    final EditText newuser = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.newuser);
    final EditText newuserpassword = (EditText)  this.findViewById(R.id.newuserpassword);
    final EditText EmailAddress = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.user_email);



    TextView neighbourView = new TextView(this);

    Button button_test2;
    button_test2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button_test2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {


        public void onClick(View s) {

            final String newusersname = newuser.getText().toString();
            final String newpasswoord = newuserpassword.getText().toString();
            final String newusermail = EmailAddress.getText().toString();


            ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
            user.setUsername(String.valueOf(newusersname));
            user.setPassword(String.valueOf(newpasswoord));
            user.setPassword(String.valueOf(newusermail));



            user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done( com.parse.ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);
                    } else {
                        // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
                        // to figure out what went wrong
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choose a differnt username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                    //if e != null, something went wrong
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

My XML is

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#372c24"
        android:text="New User Name"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:id="@+id/newuser" />

    <!--  Password Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#372c24"
        android:text="@string/password"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:password="true"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:id="@+id/newuserpassword"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


    <!--  Email Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#372c24"
        android:text="E-Mail"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:id="@+id/user_email" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Done"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

And here is my ParseApplication method

```
   public class ParseApplication extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxxx ", "xxxx");
    //...Rest of the Parse initializations.
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get the toast message? if you get it, try printing the exception message. Log.i("error",e.getMessage()); under Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choose a differnt username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: I didn't get the error message

Comment: Would you add Log.i messages to multiple places in your on click to see if the onclick is getting called?

Comment: There isn't no error message being displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not have logged out from your previous session. Add a log out logic and check.

Replace this

```
 final String newusersname = newuser.getText().toString();
            final String newpasswoord = newuserpassword.getText().toString();
            final String newusermail = EmailAddress.getText().toString();


            ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
            user.setUsername(String.valueOf(newusersname));
            user.setPassword(String.valueOf(newpasswoord));
            user.setPassword(String.valueOf(newusermail));
```

with this

```
 final String newusersname = newuser.getText().toString();
            final String newpasswoord = newuserpassword.getText().toString();
            final String newusermail = EmailAddress.getText().toString();

if(ParseUser.getCurrentUser()!=null)
        {
            ParseUser.getCurrentUser().logOut();
        }

            ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
            user.setUsername(String.valueOf(newusersname));
            user.setPassword(String.valueOf(newpasswoord));
            user.setPassword(String.valueOf(newusermail));
```

Comment: 06-27 03:06:53.125  11544-11544/com.example.dam.loginsample I/error﹕ invalid session token

Answer (score 0):

**try this saveInBackground() method that save the user.**

```
       ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
        user.setUsername(String.valueOf(newusersname));
        user.setPassword(String.valueOf(newpasswoord));
        user.setPassword(String.valueOf(newusermail));

        user.saveInBackground();
```

Comment: can u use Parse.initialize to initialize ??

Comment: pass two parameter  parseId and parseSecret

Answer (score 0):

I'm New to this but I think the issue maybe that you trying to assign 2 passwords,

for my understanding its a field you cant duplicate and granted email has a separate field already built inside the user object

```
        user.setUsername(String.valueOf(newusersname));
        user.setPassword(String.valueOf(newpasswoord));
        user.setEmail(String.valueOf(newusermail));
```